# View with relationship in field collection

Tags: views, entities

I have a contentype „roomtype“ with the fields „title“, „image“ and „text“.
And i have a contenttype called „pricelist“ containing a multivalue fieldcollection which contains the fields „roomreference“ and „price“; it is multivalue because you can add prices for low- and peakseason; there are multiple nodes of type „pricelist“ since pricelists for the years 2014, 2015, 2016 are online simulatneously.
Now i want a view showing me „image“, „text“ and the seasonal prices for every roomtype. The layout should look like this:

```
Roomtype #1
<title>
<image>
<text>

Year 2014
<prices peak season>
<prices low season>

Year 2015
<prices peak season>
<prices low season>


Roomtype #2
<title>
<image>
<text>

Year 2014
<prices peak season>
<prices low season>

Year 2015
<prices peak season>
<prices low season>

.
.
.
```

I was not able to figure out the right configuration of my view, somehow the necessary relationshipping and grouping combined with the a fieldcollection seems to be a challenge for me, i am confused where to start.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be easily done with the Display Suite module. I would use 3 views on 1 page using the main filter on RoomType. Then use DS as needed to output the ordering of fields you want. You might be able to use field_group with DS to more easily theme the whole page.

Comment: I know DS pretty well, but i don't understand your concept of 3 views, because they can not just follow each, they have to "penetrate" each other for my desired layout. What are the 3 views you are talking about, and what do you mean by "main filter"?

Comment: Views can contain other views. Look at the module Views Field View (other modules, like Panels allows the same thing to embed multiple views on 1 page). These modules allow you to pass unique parameters to each view as needed. By main filter I just mean it looks like you'd want a `contextual filter` of `date (Year)` placed on each of the multiple views on that page.

Comment: Dear tenken, i installed Views Field View and tried to manage your suggestion for days now but could not succeed. The problem is, i have no clue what fields to put in which view, where to put the relationship, etc. If you could give me a bit more advice i would be very glad.